# Vue - Pass props into vuex store?

Tags: django, vuex, vue-props

I want to pass initial data into my vuex store as a prop from my template. I am using Django templates and loading vue and vuex via script tags. Is this possible?

Example:

*index.html*

```
{{ initial_data }}  <!-- Sent from django views -->
<script src="{% static 'project/js/store.js' %}"></script>.
```

Comment: why are You using django templates + vue ? I mean, more common way is using vue + DRF. The thing that you are trying to make right now is more similar to server side rendering, but in vue case you could just use nuxt https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-a-universal-application-with-nuxt-js-and-django

Comment: Thanks for the link @Take_Care_. I am using django templates + vue for legacy reasons. Would be interested to know if you have any further suggestions.